# Set Hostname binding and https with owin selfhosted website, WITHOUT iis

Tags: binding, owin, hostname, self-hosting

How do you bind the hostname?
In short: I need this for a selfhosted website without iis:

[image: iis binding]

I have found how to bind the certificate, but not how to bind the hostname.

`netsh.exe http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:82 certstorename=Root certhash=... appid={12345678-db90-4b66-8b01-88f7af2e36bf}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use netsh http add sslcert **hostnameport**="yoursite.com:443" ...
as described here https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/23/Use-Powershell-to-bind-SSL-Certificates-to-an-IIS-Host-Header-Site